# Event OnClick on a TextBox ? (C# Win8)

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking for an event like "OnClick" on a TextBox.

My goal is just to erase the text when the user click on the TextBox.

I'm working on VS2012 for Windows 8.

Thanks.

Comment: What about `MouseLeftButtonDown` or `MouseButtonDown` (can't remember which one applies)

Comment: I have no such events in my VisualStudio = / (it's for a textbox)

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: This sounds like bad user experience unless you're going to put some checks in to see whether the current `TextBox.Text` doesn't equal your prevalue (which is presume this is why you want this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the `GotFocus` event.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `Tapped` event? This pretty much the new `Click` or `Clicked` event for touch based Windows development which includes Windows 8 store apps and Windows Phone apps

Comment: Well, i thought yes, but it didn't work.
When i click on it, it doesn't fire it.

Comment: The event is probably handled as part of the `GotFocus` event.